# Task for gradle finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: spring-boot, gradle

Good day!

This morning I fixed some methods and yaml properties in my spring app. I ran all tests, including integration with spring context but I cant run the app itself:
[image]

What did I try to solve the problem:

- invalidate caches and restart IDEA;
- gradle clean/build;
- switching JDK in Idea;
- reseting code and properties recent modification;
  ..and I still havent succeeded yet. Suggestions?

Comment: Screenshots of output are rarely useful...  Clipped screenshots less so.  What's the actual output? Can you edit your question, and paste it in its entirety into a code block?

Comment: It didn't provide any specific info at all. Just fail of gradle task bootRun etc.

Answer (score 0):

Solved after removing .gradle,.idea, /build from project and re-build it again.